# Lambda calculus: Call by value / Call by name (lazy)

Tags: lambda, evaluation, lambda-calculus

Having difficulties deciding which rules to apply on by value / by name evaulation.
Say I have:

```
(λz.zz)(λb.b)
```

And I want to evaluate according to call by valute, will the next step be

```
(λz.z)(λb.b)
```

(evaluate the left side - z apply on z),
or

```
(λz.(λb.b)(λb.b))
```

(evaluate the right side first)

And how does the evluation goes for call by name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to apply

```
(λz.zz)
```

to the argument

```
(λb.b)
```

- Call by value means: reduce the argument to normal form and then bind the parameter `z` to it
- Call by name means: replace each occurrence of the parameter `z` in the body of the function by the unevaluated argument

Since λb.b is already in normal form, it does not make a difference whether you use call by name or call by value: in both cases you will end up replacing each occurrence of `z` by `λb.b`, giving

```
(λb.b) (λb.b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these steps is correct, there is only one reducible expression in that term so in both cases the only valid step is to `(\b. b)(\b. b)`. You are only allowed to perform a reduction when applying a lambda abstraction and there is only one place where you are doing that, namely on the outermost level.